# Dagger2: Error when two components has same inject method signature

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have this component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = OauthModule.class)
public interface OauthComponent {

    void inject(LoginActivity a);

}
```

and the module:

```
@Module
public class OauthModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Oauth2Service provideOauth2Service() {
        return new Oauth2StaticService();
    }

}
```

and this another component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = LoggedUserModule.class)
public interface LoggedUserComponent {

    void inject(LoginActivity a);

}
```

and I get this error:

> Error:(15, 10) error: Oauth2Service cannot be provided without an
>   @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

If I change the `LoggedUserComponent`'s inject method parameter to be another `Activity`, say `AnotherActivity` like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = LoggedUserModule.class)
public interface LoggedUserComponent {

    void inject(AnotherActivity a);

}
```

compilation is ok. Why? Can't I have two components with the same inject signature?

I'm trying to understand how `Dagger` works so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of `dagger` as an object graph—which it actually is. You probably should *not* have 2 different components being able to inject the same object, other than for testing purposes (or if you want to include different behavior, not additional one).

If your `LoginActivity` depends on multiple modules, you should aggregate them in a single component, since as your error shows, dagger will fail if it can not provide *all* dependencies from a single component.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {LoggedUserModule.class, OauthModule.class})
public interface LoggedUserComponent {

    void inject(AnotherActivity a);

}
```

---

Looking at `Oauth2Service`, this could easily be something that multiple objects could use, so a higher scope could be adequate. In that case you should think about adding it with a `@Singleton` scope to your application component, or maybe create its own component with e.g. a `@UserScope`.

Then you would have to either make your `LoggedUserComponent` a `@Subcomponent` or declare this component a dependency using `@Component(dependencies = OauthComponent.class)` and providing a getter in `OauthComponent` for it. In both cases dagger would also be able to provide the dependency found higher in the graph, thus also resolving your error.

Answer (score 0):

It's getting mad because you're saying you can inject into that class but you're not providing a class that it's expecting you to provide. You just need to add the OauthModule to your LoggedUserComponent. Try this

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {LoggedUserModule.class, OauthModule.class})
public interface LoggedUserComponent {

    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);

}
```

Comment: What if my OAuthModule is singleton? i will never be able to inject?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking